# How to go to another View Controller when an element inside table view is being tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a UIView inside a TableViewCell,when users tapped in this UIView,it go to another view controller and pass a data along.

**So inside TableViewCellClass I done the following :**

I set up a protocol and detected the "Tap" gesture,when user table the UIView.This part is working fine:

```
protocol MyDelegate : class {
        func runThisFunction(myString : String)
}

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        weak var delegate : MyDelegate?

        ...other code here

        //here detect the tap 
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hereTapped))
        self.myUIElementInThisCell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

@objc func hereTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil){
    self.delegate?.runThisFunction(myString: "I am a man")
}
```

**So in my view controller which contain this TableView,I done the following :**

I extend out the `MyDelegate` as subclass,and then attach the protocol function inside it as below

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController,MyDelagate{

func runThisFunction(myString : String) {
     print("Tapped in view controller")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue",sender : self)
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tableViewCell = MyTableViewCell()
    tableViewCell.delegate = self
 }
}
```

**Result:**

After done all the stuff above,when I tapped the `UIView`,it didnt perform the segue as stated in `MyViewControllerClass`,even the `print()` command also didnt execute.

So what I missing out? Please give me a solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
// you create a new cell
let tableViewCell = MyTableViewCell()
// set its delegate
tableViewCell.delegate = self
// and then the cell is not used for anything else
```

Basically you are not setting the delegate for the cells that are being presented, but for another instance that you create in `viewDidLoad`.

You have to set a delegate in `cellForRowAt` to make sure the proper cells get the `delegate` set:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

This will set the `delegate` for those cells, that are presented.

---

Alternatively, I would recommend using `didSelectRowAt` from `UITableViewDelegate` (if your `MyViewController` implements it):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // only if it is the first cell (I assume that MyTableViewCell is first)
        runThisFunction(myString: "I am a man")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these 2 lines:

```
let tableViewCell = MyTableViewCell()
tableViewCell.delegate = self
```

are not related to the shown cells in the table , it's a cell created on the fly so

set delegate in `cellForRow` for the cell that you will actually waiting a delegate trigger from them

```
 cell.delegate = self
```

like this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = areaSettTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:cellID) as! MyTableViewCell
         cell.delegate = self
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the delegate for `MyTableViewCell` instances is not defined.

When you do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tableViewCell = MyTableViewCell()
    tableViewCell.delegate = self
}
```

You are setting a delegate for an object that will be destroyed just when the method `viewDidLoad()` finishes.

**Solution 1**

In order to avoid this, you have to set the delegate inside the `cellForRow` method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self

    // Other configurations

    return cell
}
```

**Solution 2**

You can also use the `UITableViewDelegate` methods in order to capture the user interaction with the cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue",sender : self)
}
```

This way you avoid all the `MyDelegate protocol` thing. This would be my preferred option.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation in not very good here, indeed if you want to change object that didn't passed to the cell explictitly.

My advice is to use closure:

```
typealias CellTapHandler = (String)->()

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var handler: CellTapHandler?

    @objc func hereTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        handler?("String or whatever you want to get back from cell.")
    }
    //...
}
```

and set up it from view controller

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", for: indexPath) 
    (cell as? MyTableViewCell).handler = { [weak self] string in  } 
    return cell
}
```

PS: As I said, usually you want to pass object related to cell further. It's difficult to do with delegation, as you had to pass to cell some additional token, to determine object by the cell, o pass object itself breaking Model-View separation paradigm. But it can be done easily with closures:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let object = self.myData[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier", for: indexPath) 
    (cell as? MyTableViewCell).handler = { [weak self] string in  
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue",sender : object)
    } 
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if (let myObj = sender as? MyObjType, let subsequentVC = segue.destination as? NextViewController) {
           subsequentVC.selectedMyObject = myObj
     }
}
```

Comment: how is closure better than delegation?

Comment: In this particular case 1) it is much more useful, 2) less code to write and support 3)easier to read and understand 4) It conforms to modern tendencies and practices. In general - it is just alternative, and not golden bullet, so in some other cases delegation can have advantages.

Comment: #1 how is it more useful? it does exactly the same thing.. #2 lets say this is true.. #3 disputable, depends on what you are used to.. #4 maybe..

Comment: #1 It's not doing same thing: you can't capture objects in delegate, so you had to provide additional tokens and by those increase complexity, you had to declare additional protocols, again increasing complexity, you had to divide your code in parts, again increasing complexity #3 'course it is, but in closure you had all code in one place, and it is less code, in delegate you had to jump between different fragments, even different files. Delegate much "heavier" from logical perspective.